# Create a directory in C for Kernel driver

Tags: c, windows, wdk

I have been recently looking into creating a miniFilter using the WDK (windows driver kit). I am struggling to find good Api reference for C. For example i want to create a directory in the following format but cannot find any references and how to do any of it.

Format of the UNICODE_STRING -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\WDKRemoteUser\Desktop'

For those people who develop in C I take my hat off to you people.

B.n I am doing all the development in Visual Studio 2017

Ok i have created a function:

```
NTSTATUS create_directory(UNICODE_STRING dirName) {
IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
NTSTATUS Status;
HANDLE FileHandle = NULL;
FILE_OBJECT *FileObj;

DbgPrint("Directory :- '%wZ'", &dirName);

InitializeObjectAttributes(
    &ObjectAttributes,
    &dirName,
    (OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE |
        OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE),
    NULL,
    NULL
);


Status = ZwCreateFile(
    &FileHandle,
    GENERIC_READ | SYNCHRONIZE,
    &ObjectAttributes,
    &iosb,
    0,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    FILE_OPEN,
    FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE,
    NULL,
    0
);

return Status;
}
```

I think i have followed the syntax correctly from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatefile

But it doesn't seem to create a directory, guessing i have got one of the parameters slightly incorrect.

I took a copy from a MS example for creating a file and modified it for what i believe is to create a directory.

Thanks

Comment: This is what I tried: google "c win32 mkdir" and after two hops I landed on [MSDN: _mkdir, _wmkdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx). If I remember right the `w` functions of Win32 expect [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (but you may verify this). Btw. `'\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\WDKRemoteUser\Desktop'` should work with non-`w` as well - these are all ASCII characters.)

Comment: Ok cool thanks, looks to be suitable and the project found the direct.h, i need to try including win32 in my searches. I kept find C++ examples

Comment: What do you mean with "in Kernel driver"? Does it mean any restriction to use Win32 functions?

Comment: Yeah there seems to be restrictions to what function and what headers are available. A lot of the functions seem to start with RTL. I am building a filesys minifilter as a WindowsKernelModeDriver. I am completely unfamiliar with C so it might just be down to me.

Comment: The lower level of `_mkdir()` is probably [CreateDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx). Please, note, it's a macro. For UTF-16 you may use `CreateDirectoryW()` explicitly.

Comment: [`IoCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatefile) or `ZwCreateFile` (depend from previous mode)

Comment: @Scheff - The lower level of `_mkdir()` is `ZwCreateFile`

Comment: @RbMm I'm happy that I used "probably". ;-) I'd sugguest you to write _the_ answer.

Comment: but this is trivial. directory is always created by `**CreateFile` with `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` option

Comment: `FILE_OPEN` disposition Open the existing file. you need `FILE_OPEN_IF ` or `FILE_CREATE`. also - who will be close file handle after create ?

Comment: All working - thanks everyone appreciate it. The above code has been updated to show working code

Comment: @user1403598 No, please don't update the code in the question to show the solution. Post it as answer instead. I rolled it back.

Comment: Apologies i dont ever get chance to answer my own questions. I know now for the future.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question and confirmed the working code is below also added the ZwClose on the handle. Thanks to everyones comments

```
NTSTATUS create_directory(UNICODE_STRING dirName) {
IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
NTSTATUS Status;
HANDLE FileHandle = NULL;
FILE_OBJECT *FileObj;

DbgPrint("Directory :- '%wZ'", &dirName);

InitializeObjectAttributes(
    &ObjectAttributes,
    &dirName,
    (OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE |
        OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE),
    NULL,
    NULL
);


Status = ZwCreateFile(
    &FileHandle,
    GENERIC_READ,
    &ObjectAttributes,
    &iosb,
    0,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL| SYNCHRONIZE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    FILE_CREATE,
    FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE,
    NULL,
    0
);

if (FileHandle) {
    ZwClose(FileHandle);
}

return Status;
}
```